# Url Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a site http://www.example.com/m/controller/function

Today I have removed the directory /m/ from all of the scripts. I want to redirect all of the links which have /m/ to same URL, but without /m/

E.g.

```
example.com/m/c/f
```

Redirects to

```
example.com/c/f
```

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the below to issue a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect to any path starting with m/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Redirect permanent /m http://www.example.com/
```

You can use mod_rewrite but it is unnecessary for this particular task and will use more system resources than need be as it has to execute a Regex. See [this for Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [this for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/remapping.html).